# Apple keeps rejecting in-app purchase submission

Tags: in-app-purchase

My IAP keeps getting rejected for reason: "We have returned your in-app purchase products to you as the required binary was not submitted. When you are ready to submit the binary, please resubmit the in-app purchase products with the binary."

On my IAP page there is no place to select or attach a binary! The binary is uploaded under the test flight tab. no matter how i tell them it's uploaded and there's no place to attach it to the IAP page they just reject with the reason. What am i doing wrong?